# Objective-C Runtime: best way to check if class conforms to protocol?

Tags: objective-c, runtime

I have a Class (but no instance) and need to know if it conforms to a certain protocol. However, Class can be subclassed several times and class_conformsToProtocol() ignores protocols declared on superclasses.

I could just use class_getSuperclass() and recursively check all the classes in the hierarchy upwards until the superclass is nil. However I wonder if that might be inefficient for deeply nested class hierarchies, and maybe there's a nicer way to do that?

In other words, how is the NSObject method conformsToProtocol best implemented using Objective-C runtime methods so that it finds protocols on superclasses?

```
 [myObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)];
```

If I'm on the right track with recursively going up the class hierarchy just let me know.

Answer (score 314, accepted):

[According to the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1418893-conformstoprotocol?language=objc),

```
[MyClass conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)];
```

should work.

Comment: You're right. It was late and no code completion suggestions were made by Xcode. I checked the definition of Class and seeing that it was "typedef struct objc_class *Class" I didn't check the NSObject class reference.

Comment: Is there any way to do it on an instance instead of a class?  My `self.delegate` implements multiple protocols and I want to check if it conforms to others than it's class.

Comment: @KonradPiascik Just call it on the instance instead: `[someObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)]`.

Answer (score 4):

Or, in case it is a general pointer, like:

```
Class<MyProtocol> someClassPointer = nil;
```

you can use:

```
[someClassPointer.class conformsToProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)];
```

Answer (score -1):

## check if class conforms to protocol?

### Two Method

#### use `conformsToProtocol`

- syntax

  - `[someClassObj conformsToProtocol: objc_getProtocol("YourProtocolName")]`
- example

```objectivec
(lldb) po self
<AKAnisetteProvisioningService: 0x105f16870>

(lldb) po Protocol * $akaisdProto = objc_getProtocol("AKAppleIDSigningDaemonProtocol")
(lldb) po $akaisdProto
<Protocol: 0x1dc7d2e90>

(lldb) po [self conformsToProtocol: $akaisdProto]
0x0000000000000001
```

#### use `class_conformsToProtocol`

- syntax

  - `class_conformsToProtocol(NSClassFromString(@"YourClassName"), objc_getProtocol("YourProtocolName"))`
- example

```objectivec
(lldb) po Class $akapsClass = NSClassFromString(@"AKAnisetteProvisioningService")
(lldb) po $akapsClass
AKAnisetteProvisioningService

(lldb) po Protocol * $akaisdProto = objc_getProtocol("AKAppleIDSigningDaemonProtocol")
(lldb) po $akaisdProto
<Protocol: 0x1dc7d2e90>

(lldb) po class_conformsToProtocol($akapsClass, $akaisdProto)
0x0000000000000001
```