# How to assert your AppDelegate has a specific protocol with ocunit?

Tags: objective-c, ocunit

I'm trying to verify that my AppDelegate object has a specific protocol

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>
```

Currently the test below adds some value but does a custom assert exist that would allow me to verify what protocols a specific object has?

```
- (void)testAppDelegateIsUiResponder
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    STAssertTrue([appDelegate isKindOfClass:[UIResponder class]], @"AppDelegate is not UIResponder");
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective-C Runtime: best way to check if class conforms to protocol?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436257/objective-c-runtime-best-way-to-check-if-class-conforms-to-protocol)

Comment: fair comment -added my final test anyway (might get closed regardless)

Answer (score 2):

As indicated by the comment - this does the trick: 
[someObject conformsToProtocol:@protocol(WhatEver)];

Answer (score 0):

@Jim mentioned another question that had the answer I was looking for. I simply added an assert true statement to get my assertion to fail as expected

```
- (void)testAppDelegateIsUiResponder
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    STAssertTrue([appDelegate isKindOfClass:[UIResponder class]], @"AppDelegate is not UIResponder");
}

- (void)testAppDelegateHasUiApplicationDelegateProtocol
{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[AppDelegate alloc] init];
    STAssertTrue([appDelegate conformsToProtocol:@protocol(UIApplicationDelegate)], @"Protocol Missing");
}
```