# How to check whether a protocol contains certain method programatically in Objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, protocols

Is there any way to check whether a protocol contains certain method or whether a method belongs to certain protocol in Objective-C?

I don't think the [redirected question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3436257) is the same as mine. What I want is:

`[MyProtocol containsSelector:@selector(MySelector)];`

Or

`[MySelector isMethodOfProtocol:@protocol(MyProtocol)];`

Comment: @Dominic - That seems like a different question, whether a class conforms to a protocol or not. The question here is whether a protocol contains a particular method or not. I'm just unclear as to _why_ Lizhen needs this, as this strikes me as something that doesn't require any runtime checks. You can determine this at compile time.

Comment: I think the only way to check is with `respondsToSelector`, and to use it you need an instance of the protocol (`something.delegate` in my answer). If you don't want to keep the delegate if `respondsToSelector` returns `NO`, you just have to do is `delegate = nil;`

Comment: @Rob - Here's what I'm going to do: If the selector is contained in a certain protocol, it will be forwarded. If not, nothing happened.

Comment: @Dominic Could you undo your redirection? Since they are two different question :)

Comment: @LizhenHu now you have edited your question and made it clearer, yes you are correct (I have deleted the comment)

Comment: @Dominic Thanks, actually I mean the header of the question, which says **"This question may already have an answer here..."**, still there :)

Answer (score 2):

See the Objective-C runtime functions

```
Protocol *objc_getProtocol(const char *name)

struct objc_method_description *protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList(Protocol *p, BOOL isRequiredMethod, BOOL isInstanceMethod, unsigned int *outCount)
```

The documentation can, at the time of this writing, be found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ObjCRuntimeRef/#//apple_ref/c/func/objc_getProtocol).

Comment: This is what I want! Thanks, @Avi :) However, my vote on your answer can't be displayed right now due to my poor reputation :(

Answer (score 2):

If you know the name of the method, here is what you can do :

First set the delegate of the protocol.
Then, check if the method belongs to the protocol as this :

```
if ([something.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(someMethodToCheck)])
```

Comment: Here's what I'm going to do: If the selector is contained in a certain protocol, it will be forwarded. If not, nothing happened. So your answer can't do the job in my case. Thanks though :)

Comment: What do you mean by "it will be forwarded" ?  `respondsToSelector` doesn't perform the selector, so if it returns YES, let's perform it, otherwise, do nothing. Am I wrong ?

Comment: I am doing this in `-forwardingTargetForSelector:`, and this method can accept other selectors, in addition to those belonging to MyProtocol. And I just want to forward the latter ones.

Comment: That only checks whether the delegate implements it, it doesn't tell you if the method is part of the protocol.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a small code snippet I am using right now (thanks to [Avi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37876351/1685709) above):

```
- (BOOL)isSelector:(SEL)selector
        ofProtocol:(Protocol *)protocol {
  unsigned int outCount = 0;
  struct objc_method_description *descriptions
  = protocol_copyMethodDescriptionList(protocol,
                                       YES,
                                       YES,
                                       &outCount);
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < outCount; ++i) {
    if (descriptions[i].name == selector) {
      free(descriptions);
      return YES;
    }
  }
  free(descriptions);
  return NO;
}
```

You can move this to a category on `NSObject` too, if you use forwarding extensively.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function I found Apple using:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

BOOL MHFProtocolHasInstanceMethod(Protocol *protocol, SEL selector) {
    struct objc_method_description desc;
    desc = protocol_getMethodDescription(protocol, selector, NO, YES);
    if(desc.name){
        return YES;
    }
    desc = protocol_getMethodDescription(protocol, selector, YES, YES);
    if(desc.name){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Use like this:

```
- (id)forwardingTargetForSelector:(SEL)aSelector{
    if(MHFProtocolHasInstanceMethod(@protocol(UITableViewDelegate), aSelector)){
    ...
```